# Send select value to an input text

Tags: angular, angularjs

I need to send the value of a select that is in one component to an input text of another component.

As you can see in the image when I select company and workshop and once I click on orders it takes me to another page where I want the value selected in the previous screen to appear in an input text.

[Pág. 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQv1V.jpg)

[Pág. 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62m6R.jpg)

This is my select:

```
  <select class="form-select">
    <option selected>SELECCIONA LA EMPRESA</option>
    <option [value]="item" *ngFor="let item of empresa">{{item}} 
    </option>
  </select>
```

And this is my input text:

```
<div>
  <div class="badge bg-primary text-wrap">
    <input type="text"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

I have tried to do it through queryParams but it has not worked.

The components are at the same level, they are brothers.

Comment: Take a look on the Tour Of Heroes https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes which explains the basics of angular also answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

Hey it is not a BIG DEAL...!

I tried the below option. It works for me. I took 2 components (componentA and componentB). Here, I am sending data from componentA to componentB.

-----HTML code of componentA; *(see image1)* -----

```
<select  class="form-select" [(ngModel)]="selectValue" placeholder="car">
    <option value="" disabled selected="selected">SELECCIONA LA EMPRESA</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of empresa" value="{{item}}"> {{item}} </option>
</select>

<button (click)="orders()">ORDERS</button>
```

Above, I have used `[(ngModel)]="selectValue"` to communicate with the componentA's class file(*component-a.component.ts*). Using this method, the selected value of the select tag is assigned to a variable (**selectValue**).

-----TypeScript code of componentA;-----

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component-a',
    templateUrl: './component-a.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./component-a.component.css']
})
export class ComponentAComponent {

   selectValue: any = "";
   empresa = ['Sample1', 'Sample2']

   constructor(private router: Router){}

   orders(){
       this.router.navigate(['/componentB'], {queryParams:{data: this.selectValue}});
   }
}
```

Above, I have used **queryParams** technique to parse the data through the URL.

-----TypeScript code of componentB;-----

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component-b',
    templateUrl: './component-b.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./component-b.component.css']
})
export class ComponentBComponent implements OnInit{

    name: any;
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}

    ngOnInit(): void{
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: any)=>{
            this.name = params.data;
        })
    }
}
```

Above, I subscribed to **queryParams** and assigned the data to a variable (**name**) to use it within componentB.

-----HTML code of componentB; *(see image3)* -----

```
<div>
    <div class="badge bg-primary text-wrap">
        <input type="text" value="{{name}}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

The data is shown here using **interpolation** technique...

[image1 - selecting an option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2X5T.png)
[image2 - click on ORDERS button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2LtG.png)  [image3 - Data is shown in componentB (inside the text field)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvsmx.png)

Comment: If I had two selectors and two input text, how could I pass two parameters?

Comment: Hey happy to listen that!..

Comment: You can have a new select tag and change the ngModel name and create a variable inside the .ts file with the same name where you used for ngModel in the HTML file.


then you can copy and paste the code line inside the orders method and do the changes accordingly. 

   ----> 
  orders(){
    console.log("the value: ", this.selectValue);
    this.router.navigate(['/componentB'], {queryParams:{data: this.selectValue, dataTwo: this.selectValueTwo}});
  }


(here, "dataTwo: this.selectValueTwo" is the new one)

Comment: Change ngOnInit() method in .ts file of componentB as bellow;

  ngOnInit(): void{
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: any)=>{
      console.log(params)
      this.name = params.data;
      this.nameTwo = params.dataTwo;
    })
  }

now dataTwo is coming through PARAMS. Create a new variable and assgin it and use within the HTML file using Interpolation